# Unity Cursor - OnMouseEnter picks up all colliders, make it react to only what I want

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a mouse cursor that I want to react when it enters certain `GameObjects`, for example if you MouseOver a flower and click, you pick it up, but if you mouseover an NPC and click, you start a dialog.

I got the basics down, but my problem is that as soon as a collider that I don't want my mouse to interact with, for example my player, moves in front it just stops working, I guess because the players collider gets in the way.

My MouseOver script (in below example I add a herb to inventory on click):

```c#
private void Update()
{
    if (mouseOver && GameManager.manager.mainState == GameManager.MainState.PLAY)
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1))
        {
            if (invMngr.AddItem(herbManager.herbId)) //check if room in inventory
            {
                Destroy(gameObject); //if there is room; Add item and destroy from world
            }
        }
    }
}

private void OnMouseEnter()
{
    Debug.Log("Mouse enter: " + gameObject);
    mouseOver = true;
}

private void OnMouseExit()
{
    Debug.Log("Mouse exit: " + gameObject);
    mouseOver = false;
}
```

There are 2 things I don't like about my approach.

1. I have to attach this Script to every `GameObject` that I want the mouse to react to, wouldnt it be better to just have 1 instance of the script in the Game Manager running at all times?.
2. I can't control which colliders it should react to, like when adding a `LayerMask` to `Raycast`. Sure it only react if it hovers over a `GameObject` that has the Script attached, but if players collider overlaps the flower, it just stops working.

How can I script a cursor so that I know what `GameObject` I'm overlapping (I do that now but surely 1 instance of the script would be better?), and so that I can control which colliders (or Layers) it should react to and which it should ignore?

Comment: If you want just one instance of script to do that then you've got to use Raycast. Although I don't recommended raycast so that's why I didn't put a solution for this. I assume this is a 3D object with 3D collider so see #6  and the `MeshDetector` script from the duplicated question.

Comment: You can make a public variable named `isClicked` and add inside the `MeshDetector` script. When there is a click, set it to `true` in the `OnPointerClick` function then set it to false after one frame in the `Update` function. You can access this variable from the GameManager script.

Comment: Thanks didnt see this question. My game is 2D. But with the help of that answer you linked I should be able to piece a solution together :) Thank you! Should I remove this question?

Comment: Use #7 if you are using 2D collider with SpriteRenderer. Every function that works in #1 should also work in #7 so check out supported functions in #1. If you have a problem let me know. You don't have to delete this unless you are getting down-votes.

Comment: @Programmer Like all your other solutions this works perfectly. Dont underrestimate how much beginners like me appriciate that you take the time to help out. You are awesome man!

Comment: Glad I was able to help you.